# Is there a way to call a function on each step change of <input type='range'>?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have simple bootstrap slider in HTML and I want it to show a value that a user selects while the user still deciding on  the value.

html right now:

```
<div  class="container-sm position-fixed w-25 bottom-0 end-0">
   <label for="customRange1" class="form-label" #zoom_label>Example range</label>
   <input type="range" class="form-range" id="customRange1" min="0.2" max="5.0" step="0.1" 
   #zoom (mousedown)="test2(zoom, zoom_label)">
</div>
```

I am using Angular 12; I tried using an OnChange event but that only calls a function when a user changes the slider's position. OnMouseDown seems to be making calls but the input's value doesn't change as expected.

Comment: onInput perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `input` event instead:

```html
<div  class="container-sm position-fixed w-25 bottom-0 end-0">
   <label for="customRange1" class="form-label" #zoom_label>Example range</label>
   <input type="range" class="form-range" id="customRange1" min="0.2" max="5.0" step="0.1" 
   #zoom (input)="test2(zoom, zoom_label)">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i honestly didn't even know it works on range inputs